# Passing parameter into ggplot for sort order from a function

Tags: r, function, sorting, ggplot2

*I'm unable to make the ggplot sort by descending order by passing a parameter.
My function expects an input value for "x_sort" which takes the values "yes" or "no". If yes, I want the ggplot to show sorted data.*

```
score <- c(25,34,28,52,24,45,35,29)
status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor","Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
df <- data.frame(score, status)

charts <- function(my_df, xvar, yvar, x_sort){
  if(x_sort=="yes") 
    ggplot(data=my_df,
    aes( 
      x=reorder(get(var), -get(score)),  
      y=get(yvar))) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+
    labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)       
  else 
  ggplot(data=my_df,
  aes( 
    x=get(xvar),  
    y=get(yvar))) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)`
}

charts(df,"status","score","yes")
charts(df,"status","score","no")`
```

This works if you send a "no" but not when you send a "yes" to tell it to sort.

Comment: you could try using `tidyeval` to improve your code - instead of passing column names as a string, you could pass them without quotes and then use `{{ xvar }}` within the `tidyverse` functions. If you want the name as a string (e.g for the `labs`), use `deparse(substitute(xvar))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `.data` to subset instead of `get`- in addition, check for typos `var` instead of `x_var` and using `get(score)` which should be `score`

```
charts <- function(my_df, xvar, yvar, x_sort){
  if(x_sort=="yes") 
    {
    ggplot(data=my_df,
    aes( 
      x=reorder(.data[[xvar]], -score),  
      y=.data[[yvar]])) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity')+
    labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)  
  } else {
  ggplot(data=my_df,
  aes( 
    x=.data[[xvar]],  
    y=.data[[yvar]])) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')+
  labs(x = xvar, y = yvar)
}
}
```

-testing

```
charts(df,"status","score","yes")
charts(df,"status","score","no")
```